# ADK and Eclipse woes - com.android.future and USBAccessory?

Tags: android, eclipse, adk

I am trying to get [ADK (Accessory Development Kit)](http://a.android.com/demokit) set up with Eclipse, but after updating to API 12, to run the demokit Hello World, I get the 29 errors, the first few looking like:

```
com.android.future cannot be resolved, etc
UsbAccessory cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: missing imports?  errors on the imports due to missing jars?

Comment: how do i fill in the missing jars?  i tried deleting and installng the api... no do...

Comment: What happens if you try to add imports?  Do you get errors on the import lines?  Is there an ADK example project you can look at, or even copy & gut (assuming license compatibility)

Comment: Did you manage to connect your ADK board successfully to your computer? I'm having a real fight with the FTDI drivers. - That answer down below is correct by the way. That's why you're having your error. If you don't see "GOOGLE APIs", you'll need to go download them using the Android SDK and AVD manager (look under available packages)

Comment: @ina I'm facing the same problem and I'm not sure how to get through it with the written solution. any further hints? All I see under project->properties are modules to be added, that need to be located on the pc. Also I downloaded almost all the Google APIs along with all SDKs I'm using.

Answer (score 24):

You need to set your build target to Google APIs, not Android. Click on Project->Properties, then in the dialog box, select Google APIs (2.3.3) instead of Android 2.3.3.